# Python doesn't print anything when using end parameter with print from a subprocess pipe

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, subprocess

I'm trying to run a python script from within another python script using subprocesses. (No importing, I want this to work for any program, not just python)

Here is the first file: `getting_input.py`

```
name = input("Sample input prompt: ")
```

Here is the file I am using to run any shell command: `test.py`

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen("python getting_input.py", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for char in iter(lambda: proc.stdout.read(1).decode('utf-8'), ''):
    print(char)  # This actually works, printing every character on a new line
```

But when the only thing I change is add `end=""` to my print statement absolutely nothing gets printed.

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen("python getting_input.py", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for char in iter(lambda: proc.stdout.read(1).decode('utf-8'), ''):
    print(char, end="")  # This doesn't work, nothing at all gets printed... ????
```

I am assuming this is some sort of buffering issue, but even when I run it with `python -u test.py` and inside it use `python -u getting_input.py` I still see no output. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't print output show up immediately in the terminal when there is no newline at the end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25897335/why-doesnt-print-output-show-up-immediately-in-the-terminal-when-there-is-no-ne)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
print(char, end="", flush=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept this when I can, do you have any idea why this happens? Does the implicit "\n" cause the buffer to flush automatically?

Comment: Something is probably line buffering and normally only flushes on newline.