# Sleep Function Inside FOR Does Not Perform One-by-One Counting

Tags: python, class, python-class

I'm practicing creating classes and functions in Python. In a certain simple countdown exercise, I had to use the `sleep()` function inside a `FOR` loop to display the numbers one by one. The issue is that the output performs the count, but without showing the number corresponding to the thread of the `FOR` loop. In the end, the numbers appear all at once in a single print. The code is below:

```
import closed
from time import sleep

class Countdown:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def Count(self):
        for counter in range(10,-1,-1):
            print(f'{counter} ', end='')
            sleep(1)
        
        return 'Finished Counting!'


countdown = Countdown()
print(countdown.Count())
```

Just to inform you, `import closed` only serves to show a thank you message at the beginning of the program execution.

I tried taking the `FOR` loop from the `Count` method and putting it in the class call in the main part of the code below, but I got the same behavior. Thanks in advance for the responses.

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-can-i-flush-the-output-of-the-print-function

Comment: Werid I copy pasted your code and it does work, it print number from 10 to 0 with an interval of 1 second, then it print "Finished Counting!"

Comment: Also related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25897335/why-doesnt-print-output-show-up-immediately-in-the-terminal-when-there-is-no-ne

Comment: Serious? Now the doubt about what the core problem is has increased. Does it have something to do with the IDE used? I'm editing in VS Code on Windows 10.

Comment: The only difference is I did not copy the `import closed`, I also tried it in VS Code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't print output show up immediately in the terminal when there is no newline at the end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25897335/why-doesnt-print-output-show-up-immediately-in-the-terminal-when-there-is-no-ne)

Comment: @Nathan Sorry for the delay in responding. I just realized that this problem only occurs when I use the end=' ' parameter at the end of the input() so that there are spaces between the printed numbers. However, when I remove it, the count is performed normally with the time established in sleep(). The problem is linked to the end= parameter, in this case.